# Which MAGMI Github directory to use?

Tags: magmi

There's two directories in the Github respositories:

- magmi
- magmi-0.8

Which one should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this question as well. After sniffing around, it looks like the magmi-0.8 folder may be reserved for the future releases of Magmi 0.8. The current stable is 0.7.19

I tried to run the magmi-0.8 version but got a bunch of errors, so I am now running the app from the base magmi folder. Fingers crossed this version plays nicely with Magento CE 1.8

This post provides more info:
https://github.com/dweeves/magmi-git/issues/12

Answer (score 0):

This is not something standard for GitHub.

You're rather referring to [Magento Mass Importer](https://github.com/dweeves/magmi-git) project hosted on GitHub.

As you're starting now, you should use the `magmi` directory, as it has the most updated code.